# Link to anchor on another page with smooth scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, smooth-scrolling

I have searched high and low for this answer but can't seem to find it.

I have anchors on the homepage with links in the top menu that scroll to them.

This works great on the homepage but on the sub-pages it doesn't work.

Below is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        }, 2000, function(){

          // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
          window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

I have so far found that removing the **event.preventDefault()** line makes them work. But it stops the nice smooth scrolling effect.

What can be altered here so that I can have anchor links clicked on sub-pages that lead to the anchor section on the homepage with a smooth scroll ?

Comment: By *subpage* do you mean another page? If so, by *smotth scroliing on another page*, do you want something like the page loads at top and smoothly scrolls to the anchor? That points can be clarified for a prompter answer. Hope so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `return false;` instead after scroll, and remove `event.preventDefault` &  `event.stopPropagation()`

try below code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 2000, function() {

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
      return false;
    } // End if
  });
});
```

Comment: Wow thats perfect! Worked like a charm! Thanks so much for your help!!